# Expressing complex circle in polar coordinates?

Tags: complex-analysis

The circle in complex numbers has the form

$$|z-c|=r$$

or

$$\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z-c|=r\}$$

How does one express a circle (in complex form) in polar coordinates and what is the "polar coordinate form" of a complex circle?

Comment: You just asked this question. Why did you delete it and ask again?

Answer (score 7):

May be what you are looking for is
$$
z=c+r\,e^{i\theta},\quad 0\le\theta<2\,\pi?
$$

Comment: Can you explain how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Circle) would have saved you the trouble;

The general equation for a circle with center at $(r_o, \gamma)$ and radius $a$ is $$r^2 - 2rr_0\cos(\varphi - \gamma) + r_0^2 = a^2$$

Comment: So this applies to "complex circle" as well?

Comment: @mavavilj the "complex circle" and the circle in the 2d plane are exactly the same thing

Comment: What happens to $i$ when one plugs $z=|z|cos\theta+isin\theta$ to e.g. $|z-1|=1$? If $i$ is left, then it's not "really" a circle in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mavavilj in the above equation, $r = |z|$ and $\varphi = \arg z$. Also, $z = |z| \cos \theta + i |z| \sin \theta$. I don't really understand your comment...

Comment: In that case I probably need to see the derivation of the equation you posted.